# How to convert this button with onclick function to one with an id

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using the following to save my fabricjs canvas to my computer:

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn" onclick="downloadFabric(canvas,'file');">Save</button>
```

**JS**

```
function download(url, name) {
  $("<a>")
    .attr({
      href: url,
      download: name
    })[0]
    .click();
}
function downloadFabric(canvas, name) {
  download(canvas.toDataURL(), name + ".png");
}
```

Basically I'm trying to do away with the `onclick=` because I've read that this isn't the right way to handle things. I've tried writing like this without luck:

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn" id="save">Save</button>
```

**JS**

```
function download(url, name) {
  $("<a>")
    .attr({
      href: url,
      download: name
    })[0]
    .click();
}
$("#save").click(function save(canvas, name) {
    download(canvas.toDataURL(), name + ".png");
});
```

When I do the above, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check for any errors in your console?

Comment: Also, is this button added dynamically? Because if so, you'll need to delegate the event.

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: canvas.toDataURL is not a function` and no, it is not added dynamically

Comment: Your click function is wrong, you don't need `save` and it doesn't take any params other than events. See [jQuery api](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: you need to get the `canvas` and `name`  inside the `save` function rather than setting as param and then use  `$("#save").click(save);`  like this. define the save function separately like `download` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `canvas` and `name` inside the `save` function rather than setting as `param` and then use `$("#save").click(save);` to bind it to the click function . Define the `save` function separately like `download` function

See the demo below which triggers the file download with the name `file.png` from the canvas.

```js
function download(url, name) {
  $("<a>")
    .attr({
      href: url,
      download: name
    })[0]
    .click();
}

function save() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  //get the name via input val or where ever you are getting it 
  var name = 'file';
  download(dataURL, name + ".png");
}
$("#save").on('click',save);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" id="save">Save</button>

<canvas id="canvas" width="5" height="5"></canvas>
```